# $\sigma(XI_{[ X\in B ]}) = X^{-1}(B) \cap \sigma(X)$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

The following is exercise 1.4.10 from the book "Probability Theory: Independence, Interchangeability, Martingales" by Chow & Teicher:

> For any linear Borel set $B$ and random variable $X$, prove that
>   $$\sigma(XI_{[ X\in B ]}) = X^{-1}(B) \cap \sigma(X)$$
>   where $I_{[ X\in B ]}$ is the indicator function $I_{[ X\in B ]}(w) = 1 $ if $X(w)\in B $, and $=0$ otherwise.

However, I think that the statement is not always true.

For example, let $B := [0, 1]$, $X: [-\infty, \infty] \rightarrow [-\infty, \infty]$ be defined by 
$$  X(w) := \begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $w \in [-\infty, -1] $} \\
1, & \text{if $w \in (-1, 0]$ } \\
2 & \text{if $w \in (0, \infty]$ } \\
\end{cases} $$
then for $Y(w) := X(w)I_{[ X\in B ]}(w)$, 
$$ Y(w) = \begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $w \in [-\infty, -1] $} \\
1, & \text{if $w \in (-1, 0]$ } \\
0 & \text{if $w \in (0, \infty]$ } \\
\end{cases} $$
so that $Y^{-1}(\{0\}) = [-\infty, -1] \cup (0, \infty] $, which cannot be a subset of $X^{-1}(B) = [-\infty, 0]$.

Am I correct?

Comment: What is meant by $X^{-1}(B)\cap\sigma(X)$? If it denotes the set $\{X^{-1}(B)\cap C\mid C\in\sigma(X)\}$ then we are dealing with subsets of $X^{-1}(B)$ so that the collection does not necessarily has the whole space $\Omega$ as element. In that case it is not a $\sigma$-algebra hence cannot equal the LHS.

Comment: What is the meaning of $X^{-1} (B) \cap \sigma(X)$ in the book?. The entire space $\Omega$ is in the left side of the equation it is not in the right side if you interpret $X^{-1} (B) \cap \sigma(X)$ as the collection of all sets  $X^{-1} (B) \cap E$ with $E \in \sigma (X)$.

Comment: I think the correct statement is $\sigma (XI_{[X \in B]})=\sigma(X^{-1}(B)\cap \sigma(X))$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments for clarifying the situation. I try to revise the question myself and give an answer here:

> For any linear Borel set $B$ and random variable $X$, prove that
>   $$\sigma_{ A }(XI_{A})= A \cap \sigma_{\Omega}(X)$$
>   where $A = X^{-1}(B)$.

Answer:

> $A \cap \sigma_{\Omega}(X) \\
>  = A \cap \sigma_{\Omega}(\{X^{-1}[-\infty, \alpha): -\infty < \alpha < \infty \}) \\
>  = \sigma_{ A }(\{X^{-1}[-\infty, \alpha): -\infty < \alpha < \infty \} \cap A) \\
>  = \sigma_{ A }(\{Y^{-1}[-\infty, \alpha): -\infty < \alpha < \infty \}), \\
> \text{where $Y = X_{|A}$.}
> $

Comment: On what do base the second equality in your answer? Actually $A$ is a set and $\sigma(X)$ a collection of sets. Then what is $A\cap\sigma(X)$?

Comment: @drhab it is theorem 1.3.3 from the same book

Comment: How is $A\cap\sigma(X)$ defined in your book?

Comment: @drhab $A\cap \mathfrak{D} = \{ A \cap B: B\in \mathfrak{D} \}$ for any class $\mathfrak{D}$ of subsets of $\Omega$

Comment: But in that case $A\cap\sigma(X)=\{A\cap B\mid B\in\sigma(X)\}$ and as I said every set in this collection is a subset of $A$. That means that it cannot contain $\Omega$ (unless $A=\Omega$) hence is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @drhab $\sigma_{A}(\mathfrak{D})$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the class $\mathfrak{D}$ relative to the reference space $A$

Comment: That makes things more clear. I advice you to mention this in your question by explanation of the symbol $\sigma_A$. There the index lacks. That will prevent a lot of confusion. $\sigma$ algebras relative to a space $A$ are not very common.